# Two interfaces, both require the firewall to be up before starting

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, network-interface, reboot

Say I have a couple of servers at DigitalOcean and I want them to talk to each others.

DigitalOcean offers a WAN connection and a LAN connection. Problem is that both are insecure. The WAN is the Internet and the LAN is shared by everyone who has a computer (VPS) at DigitalOcean.

So I want to block everything except a few ports such as 53, 80, 443 on the WAN. That's the standard procedure.

Then, maybe I have MySQL on the other computer so I want to open port 3306 for IP address 10.1.1.1 (sample IPs, not actually valid at DigitalOcean.)

Now my problem is that I want the firewall rules to be in place before either interface gets started.

```
auto eth0 eth1 

iface eth0 inet static
        address 8.8.8.2  # some Internet address
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        gateway 8.8.8.1  # some Internet address
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        pre-up /etc/network/firewall

iface eth1 inet static
        address 10.1.1.1
        netmask 255.0.0.0
        pre-up /etc/network/firewall
```

What I came up with is to add the `pre-up` to both interfaces. That way I'm sure it starts before either one, it also means the script will run twice.

Is that the way to do it? Or would there be a better way to have the equivalent of `pre-up` that's global to all Interfaces?

Note: OS is Ubuntu 16.04.1, latest available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution, since I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and we have systemd, I just created a script `snapinitfirewall.service` and installed it along my firewall code.

```
# Documentation available at:
# https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

[Unit]
Description=Snap! Websites firewall initialization
Before=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/etc/network/firewall
#ExecStop=... -- why would you ever want to remove your firewall rules?

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# vim: syntax=dosini
```

`/etc/network/firewall` is a script which restores all the rules at once on boot.

Because I have another service file for that one package (i.e. one package offering two services) I have to include the following line to make sure the initialization is enabled and runs on reboot:

```
systemctl -q enable snapinitfirewall
```

This is a much better approach than using the `pre-up` capability since you can be sure it runs before the network gets started.

For those interested by more, the [snapfirewall project](https://github.com/m2osw/snapcpp/tree/master/snapwebsites/snapfirewall) is on github.